How can I pass a newline in the macro argument to m4
I have an m4 template where I want to insert more than one line.
In my template I have the placeholder __CODE__. Now I want to call m4 with something like
m4 -D__CODE__="foo\nbar" template.m4

but in the output I get
foo\nbar

in place of __CODE__.
Any ideas how this could be done?

Insert a literal newline into the value that you are assigning.  You can do this in various ways:

If your shell supports $'...' strings:
m4 -D __CODE__=$'foo\nbar' template.m4


Just type a newline:
m4 -D __CODE__='foo
bar' template.m4


Use printf:
m4 -D __CODE__="$(printf 'foo\nbar')" template.m4



